PySimpleGUI popup buttons not working on display
I am writing Python code for a 10.1 inch touchscreen to display. I am using PiSimpleGUI for the interface. When I use popup windows, I am not able to click on the "ok" or "cancel" buttons on the popup with my finger, however if I use a mouse it works. In the normal windows, I can click on regular buttons to carry out my functions with my finger, but why wont it let me click the popup windows? I provide a snippet of code below to show the popup windows I am referring to.
        elif event == '-FINISH-':
            if self.selected_button:
                # Construct the message using f-string
                message = f' You Selected:          \n Hardware: {self.selected_button}\n Quantity: {values["-QUANTITY-"]}'
                # Display the popup
                popup_result = sg.popup_yes_no(message, title="", font=('Helvetica', 14), keep_on_top=True)
                if popup_result == 'Yes':
                    # Add selected hardware and quantity to the shopping list
                    hardware = self.selected_button
                    quantity = int(values['-QUANTITY-'])
                    self.add_to_shopping_list(hardware, quantity)
                    # Display the shopping list popup
                    shopping_action = self.handle_shopping_list()
                    if shopping_action == 'submit_order':
                        return State.DISPENSE_LOADING_SCREEN  # Transition to dispense loading screen
                    # Reset selected button and quantity slider
                    self.window[self.selected_button].update(button_color=('black', '#598baf'))
                    self.selected_button = None
                    self.window['-QUANTITY-'].update(5)  # Move the slider back to 5
            else:
                sg.popup_ok("Please Select Hardware Before Finishing", title="Alert", font=('Helvetica', 14),
                            keep_on_top=True)

I have tried everything I can think of.

I don't have a touchscreen like yours to do the test.
Better to post your configuration, like

What machine
OS
python version sys.version
PySimpleGUI Version sg.__version__
tkinter version sg.tclversion_detailed
What touchscreen

Try short, simple and executable script to demo your issue.
Example code
import PySimpleGUI as sg

sg.set_options(font=("Courier New", 20))
window = sg.Window("Title", [[sg.Button("POPUP", expand_x=True)]])

while True:

    event, values = window.read()

    if event == sg.WIN_CLOSED:
        break

    elif event == "POPUP":
        sg.popup_yes_no("Touch Screen", keep_on_top=True)

window.close()

Then tell us again about how it is now.
